# How to configure ResourceBundleViewResolver in Spring Framework 2.0

Tags: java, spring, frameworks

Everywhere I look always the same explanation pop ups.
Configure the view resolver.

```
<bean id="viewMappings"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver">
    <property name="basename" value="views" />
</bean>
```

And then put a file in the classpath named view.properties with some key-value pairs (don't mind the names).

```
logout.class=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView
logout.url=WEB-INF/jsp/logout.jsp
```

What does `logout.class` and `logout.url` mean?
How does `ResourceBundleViewResolver` uses the key-value pairs in the file?
My goal is that when someone enters the URI `myserver/myapp/logout.htm` the file `logout.jsp` gets served.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ResourceBundleViewResolver uses the key/vals in views.properties to create view beans (actually created in an internal application context). The name of the view bean in your example will be "logout" and it will be a bean of type JstlView. JstlView has an attribute called URL which will be set to "WEB-INF/jsp/logout.jsp". You can set any attribute on the view class in a similar way.

What you appear to be missing is your controller/handler layer. If you want /myapp/logout.htm to serve logout.jsp, you must map a Controller into /myapp/logout.htm and that Controller needs to return the view name "logout". The ResourceBundleViewResolver will then be consulted for a bean of that name, and return your instance of JstlView.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question `logout` is the view name obtained from the ModelAndView object returned by the controller. If your are having problems you many need the following additional configuration.

You need to add a servlet mapping for `*.htm` in your `web.xml`:

```
    <web-app>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>htm</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <oad-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>htm</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

And if you want to map directly to the `*.jsp` without creating a custom controller then you need to add the following bean to your Spring context:

```
    <bean id="urlFilenameController"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController" />
```